# The values of convenience initializer init(keyPath:) for CABasicAnimation

Tags: swift, swift3, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I'm using CABasicAnimation for layer animations. In convenience initializer init(keyPath:) I specify which values I want to animate, but I do it mostly intuitively. I mean, I know that it should animate layer's position.x, for example, so I use that value. But where can I find the complete list of values? I checked the documentation for both the initializer and CABasicAnimation and found just some examples of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource you are looking for is the [Key-Value Coding Extensions page of the Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html).

There are additions for properties of the types `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, `CGRect`, and `CATransform3D`.

---

### `CGPoint`

For point properties you can use `.x` and `.y`. For example:

```
"position.x" // use a number
```

---

### `CGSize`

For size properties you can use `.width` and `.height`. For example:

```
"shadowOffset.height" // use a number
```

---

### `CGRect`

For rectangle properties you can use `origin` and `size`, as well as the point and size additions on those. For example:

```
"bounds.origin.x"  // use a number
"frame.size.width" // use a number
"frame.origin"     // use a point
```

---

### `CATransform3D`

Core Animation transform properties have additions for `scale` (`.x`, `.y`, `.z`), `rotation` (`.x`, `.y`, `.z`), and `translation` (`.x`, `.y`, `.z`). For example:

```
"transform.rotation.z"    // use a number
"transform.translation.x" // use a number
```

You can also just use `.scale` as a number that scales uniformly on all axis, `.rotation` as a number for the rotation around the z-axis (same as `rotation.z`), and `.translation` as a size that translates along the x- and y-axis.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for!